# Sequelize 'where' only if req.query is defined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to consider the where clause only if 'req.query.p' is defined:

```
exports.select = function(req, res) {
        db.Pelicula
            .findAndCountAll({
                limit : req.query.limit,
                offset : req.query.offset,
                where : ["nombre = ?", req.query.p]
            })
            .success(function(resp){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.rows, null, 4).bold.get);
                res.json({peliculas : resp.rows, meta : { total : resp.count}});
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
where : req.query.p ? ["nombre = ?", req.query.p] : null
```

Comment: What if req.query.p is 'val1 : 1'

I want to filter by val1 column